# Analyzing a boolean series defined by a piecewise probability recurrence

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Say we have a probabilistic boolean series $B_n$, whose form is entirely dependent on prior values, e.g.:
$$
P(B_n) = \begin{cases}1 & \text{if }\lnot B_{n-1}\land \lnot B_{n-2}\newline \frac{4}{5} & \text{if } \lnot B_{n-1} \land B_{n-2}\newline \frac{1}{2} & \text{if } B_{n-1} \end{cases}
$$
Can we express an expected number of successes in an arbitrary range of this sequence of a given size?

Comment: The pairs $(B_{n-1},B_n)$ form a Markov chain.

Answer (score 0):

Running with @metamorphy's tip, I formulated the series as a Markov chain, with states indicating how many steps since the last success ([image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfivO.png)).

It turns out the [stationary distribution](https://brilliant.org/wiki/stationary-distributions/) for this discrete Markov process is:

$[\frac{5}{8},\frac{5}{16},\frac{1}{16}]$

This indicates the chain will roughly be in the 1st success state $\frac{5}{8} s$ of the time, and we expect a range of size $s$ to have $\frac{5}{8} s$ successes.